# How to skip a data line in fortran

Tags: fortran, line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q597E.png)

I have this data file

and want to read this data without line 1,2,3,4,5

```
   program example

   real data(15,9)
   OPEN ( unit=10, file='filename'  )
   do i = 1, 15
     READ (10, *) (data(i,j), j=1,10)
   enddo

   print *, data(4,1), data(4,2), data(4,3)

   stop
   end
```

this is my fortran code.

how can i change this code

Answer (score 1):

Looking something like this?

**input file: data**

```
line1
line2 
line3
line4 
line5
line6
line7 
line8
line9 
line10
```

**fortran code:**

```
implicit none
integer:: lskip,lread
character(len=20)::line
open(20, file = "data")
!skip first 5 line
do lskip = 1,5
  read(20,*)
End do
! First 5 lines skiped
! Now read actual lines
do lread = 1,5
  read(20,*)LINE
  write(*,*)line
End do
close(20)
end
```

**Result**

```
$gfortran so.f90
$./a.out 
 line6               
 line7               
 line8               
 line9               
 line10
```

**NB:** This is a minimal example, just for showing the skipping. You will change the read inside `lread` loop to actually read your file according to your data format

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to put in a READ statement for each line that you want to "skip". Each time a READ statement is encountered, it reads in the data and then moves the "pointer" in the file down to the next line. So, for example, to skip 3 lines of header information:

```
   DO 50 ilines = 1,3
     READ(1,*)
  50  continue
```

This in effect READs and stores nothing, but moves the pointer in the file forward 3 lines.